# How to open camera directly in panorama/photosphere mode?

Tags: android, android-camera, panoramas, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am stuck in a problem in Android 4.2 Jelly Bean.

How can I open camera from my application, by default in panorama/360 photosphere mode?

I have searched a lot in [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.2_r1/com/android/camera/Camera.java) and also [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html), but nothing seems to help. Does anybody have any clues to open camera in panorama mode apart from video and image?

Comment: use this intent action  "INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no standard way to do it.
 AFAIK Panorama, Photoshere are proprietary features of Gallery3d (provided by Google)
package com.google.android.gallery3d. It's depends on firmware of the device.

in ApplicationManifest.xml

```
<activity clearTaskOnLaunch="true" screenOrientation="0" name="com.google.android.apps.lightcycle.ProtectedPanoramaCaptureActivity" theme="resource_id:0x1030007" configChanges="1184" label="resource_id:0x7f0a00b2" windowSoftInputMode="35" taskAffinity="com.google.android.camera">
<intent-filter>
<action name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
</action>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I've tried to start this activity from my application

```
    Intent res = new Intent();
    String mPackage = "com.google.android.gallery3d";
    String mClass = "com.google.android.apps.lightcycle.ProtectedPanoramaCaptureActivity";

    res.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mClass));
    startActivity(res);
```

but it throws NullPointerException in camera app.

Comment: I'm trying to use this code to open the camera in panorama mode directly, but the manifest code gives an error, the method name is not defined. please could you update me how to use this code?

Comment: you don't need to paste anything to your manifest. use java code

Comment: But you have to declare ProtectedPanoramaCaptureActivity in manifest... How are you compiling package com.google.android.apps.lightcycle... ?

Answer (score 2):

I am also looking to open photosphere camera in my application or at least show photosphere option in normal camera.I searched lot but i didn't find any solution.

I think we don't have any solution to open photosphere camera.We need wait for next Android API release.

[How to open photosphere camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193002/how-to-open-photosphere-camera)

Answer (score 2):

you can open all default camera function using below code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
    startActivity(intent);
```