# How to open photosphere camera?

Tags: photosphere

Android API we don't have to open camera in photosphere mode.When we are opening normal camera how to show photosphere mode option in camera options.

To open normal camera I used below intents:

1)Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

2)Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

3)Intent intent=new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377663/how-to-open-camera-directly-in-panorama-mode

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it is not possible to open up the camera in Photo Sphere mode directly right now, but given enough interest I think we should add it.

Comment: Sascha, where can we manifest the interest? I would like to officially apply +1 on this ;)