# How to implement Camera functionality with extra options (like Panorama)?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, panoramas

I am mainly interested in panorama option. Is there a way to open the native Camera app (the enhanced version), so the user can switch between normal photo and panorama view? Is it possible at all or should I stop trying?

---

Here is the code that I am using right now:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

This is what currently happens:

[image]  [image]

And this is what I need to achieve:

[image]

---

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it is not yet possible to use panorama or photosphere modes directly from an application since they depend on proprietary classes provided by Google. Maybe it will be possible in the next Android API release.

See [How to open camera directly in panorama/photosphere mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15465620/1176435) or [How to open photosphere camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17375440/1176435)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do it. AFAIK Panorama, Photoshere are proprietary features of
Gallery3d (provided by Google) package com.google.android.gallery3d. It's depends on 
firmware of the device.

in manifest file

```
   <activity clearTaskOnLaunch="true" screenOrientation="0"   
   name="com.google.android.apps.lightcycle.ProtectedPanoramaCaptureActivity" 
   theme="resource_id:0x1030007" 
   configChanges="1184" 
   label="resource_id:0x7f0a00b2" 
   windowSoftInputMode="35"
   taskAffinity="com.google.android.camera">

<intent-filter>
<action name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
</action>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

in your activity

```
 Intent res = new Intent();
 String mPackage = "com.google.android.gallery3d";
 String mClass = "com.google.android.apps.lightcycle.ProtectedPanoramaCaptureActivity";
res.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mClass));
startActivity(res);
```

Comment: This won't return the path of the captured image so I don't see how it will be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

You can open paranoma mode using below code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I think this opens the camera app in "still" mode, not panorama.