# How to open panoramic mode in camera in android programatically?

Tags: android

How to use panoramic mode in android?i am builld a android project which are used take a image using panoramic mode how it is possiable?please give me answer.

Comment: Please check this link may be you will find your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193002/how-to-open-photosphere-camera

Comment: i used this url but can not get successfully responce.please let me know that it is possiable or not?