# Android : How to take vertical panorama image? Or how to stitch images in realtime?

Tags: android, android-camera, panoramas

I would like to ask.
How to take vertical panorama image? Or how to stitch images in realtime?

Exist some plugin for this or is possible to start panorama camera activity for taking vertical panorama images?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you would do this manually I would start with opening a camera. After the first picture, I would crop the image, make for 50% transparent and then overlay a part of your camera. It is possible to have a camera directly in your app. After the user took the picture you can stitch them together in a background thread.

To answer your question if it is possible to open directly the panaroma from android:

[How to open camera directly in panorama/photosphere mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377663/how-to-open-camera-directly-in-panorama-photosphere-mode)