# How to enable Camera Panorama in Android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am using default camera application to capture the image in my application. Right now it is not showing Panorama option.

My current implementation is as follows

```
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, GlobalConstants.IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
```

Any suggestions, Do I need to send some extra parameters for Panoramic mode?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15465620/2783386

Comment: @AndoMasahashi I tried pasting that activity code in my manifest but it is showing me error
Error:(95, 36) Integer types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value '1184').