# Open camera in Panorama mode

Tags: android, android-camera, panoramas, android-camera2

I am trying to implement Panorama view on android, but i cant find any help using camera API from google.

Its just that i will have a button and onclick of that open the camera in panorama mode and take picture and store in location may be in sdcard.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open camera directly in panorama/photosphere mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377663/how-to-open-camera-directly-in-panorama-photosphere-mode)

Comment: @Vyacheslav i have seen that, as you can see that there no proper solution. Please let me know if you find any solution rather than misleading that the question is duplicate.