# How to open Panorama Mode direcly android?

Tags: android, camera, 360-panorama

I want to open panorama mode of camera directly. I have tried following link.

[How to open camera directly in panorama/photosphere mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377663/how-to-open-camera-directly-in-panorama-photosphere-mode/15465620#15465620)

Have tried too many things but didn't able to open panorama mode of camera, Please help what to do.

Is there any option to open panorama mode of camera by passing extra variable with Intent?

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE").putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: The different device may not have panorama mode, so it depends devices.

Comment: @Yat3s but which devices have, how to call on that

Comment: Google cannot know how to develop this API in android SDK。